# libglvnd causes an error when updating Manjaro

Tags: linux, manjaro, software-updates

When I'm trying to update my Manjaro, I'm getting this. How can I fix it?
[image: Here's a problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what helped me.

```
sudo pacman -S mhwd mesa libglvnd lib32-mesa lib32-libglvnd --force
sudo pacman -Syu
```